# apply pagination to search results, limit 10 pages per time

Tags: php, pagination

The following piece of code, is what I use for pagination in search results. After the search results will be produced, my code will display results in the following format:  "START PREVIOUS 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 NEXT". All I want is that the pointers in pagination not to exid 10 elements. For example if search results produce 11 pages then my pagination format to be like this  "START PREVIOUS 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 NEXT" (you starts from page 2) if I press 10 to see the 10th page. I have tried some examples from stackoverflow but did not work for me.
This is my code:

```
<?php

    $prev = $page - 1;
    $next = $page + 1;

    if($prev > 1)
    echo"<a href='?value=$value'>Start</a> ";

    if($prev > 0)
    echo"<a href='?value=$value&page=$prev'>previous</a> ";


    $number=1;
    for($number; $number<=$num_pages; $number +=1)
    {


        if($page==$number)
        echo"<b> [$number] </b>";

        else
        echo"<a href='?value=$value&page=$number'> $number </a>";



    }



    if($page < ceil($num_rows/$per_page))
    echo"<a href='?value=$value&page=$next'>next</a> ";
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Do you happen to know subtraction?

Comment: if there are more than 10 pages in search results, lets say 15, then I will get "START PREVIOUS 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 NEXT". I dont want that. I want to get in this case "START PREVIOUS 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 NEXT" and when the user press page 10 to get "START PREVIOUS 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 NEXT" and so on unitl get "START PREVIOUS 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 NEXT". 10 elements each time must be displayed. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you happen to know subtraction? Say, can you subtract 10 from 15?

Comment: we are talking about case that results are more than 10 pages ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of number starting at 1 let it start at $page and limit it to 10 or til max is reached.

```
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

if($prev > 1)
echo"<a href='?value=$value'>Start</a> ";

if($prev > 0)
echo"<a href='?value=$value&page=$prev'>previous</a> ";

for($number = 0; $number < 10 && ($number + $page) < $num_pages; $number +=1)
{


    if($number = 1)
    echo"<b> [$page] </b>";

    else
    echo"<a href='?value=$value&page=" . ($number + $page) . "'> " . ($number + $page) . " </a>";



}



if($page < ceil($num_rows/$per_page))
echo"<a href='?value=$value&page=$next'>next</a> ";
```

This way it will always be selected page + 10 unless there are no more pages.

**Example (if there are only 12 pages)**

`1...10`
`2...11`
`3...12`
`4...12`
`5...12`

That being said this is, in my opinion, a terrible way of doing it. There are tons of great PHP libraries/classes that do it better and make it "generic" so you don't have to code this for every page you have pagination.